# How can I link a component's Size to the Window size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am making a simple WinForms program.
I would like to link a component's size to the size of the Window.

Let's say the user enlarges or shrinks the Window by dragging it's borders: I would like that a component gets bigger when the Window does and vice versa.

Let's pretend that we have two Buttons, in the center of the Window, side by side: I want to make them the same size filling the entire width of the Window.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use the [Anchor and Dock properties](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/)

Comment: Or add the two Buttons to a TableLayoutPanel (2 Columns, 1 Row), anchored to the left and right of the Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample procedure, using a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel) and 2 Buttons:

- Add a TableLayoutPanel to the Form

  1. Edit the Columns and Rows collections so that you have 2 Columns, both sized at `50%` and one Row, set to **`Autosize`**.
  2. Set the **`Location.X`** of the TableLayoutPanel to `0` and adjust its width to the width of the Form.
  3. Set the TLP **`Anchor`** property to **`Left`** and **`Right`**
  4. Adjust-drag the Row height to be ~twice the size of the Button it will host
- Add one Button to the Form

  1. Adjust the appearance of the Button as required.
  2. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Drag the Button to create an exact duplicate
  3. Add the two Buttons to the two cells of the TableLayoutPanel
  4. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-Select both Buttons and set the Dock property to **`DockStyle.Fill`**
  5. You can now adjust the **`Margin`** property of the Buttons (still both selected, so the same settings will apply to both) to modify the space between the controls
- Re-adjust the TableLayoutPanel's only Row height as needed.
- Extra: if you have only these controls on the Form, you may want to fix the **`MinimumSize`** of the Form, to avoid that, when the Form is resized, your controls are shrinked beyond recognition, ruining the overall layout: resize the Form in the Designer to a point where the hosted controls layout is compromised, find a suitable minimum size and use this measure as the Form's [`MinimumSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize) property. The `MinimumSize` can be set using only the `Width` or the `Height` measure (e.g., `(100, 0)`). This limits the Form's `Width` but not the `Height`. Or the opposite, of course.

> If, when dragging the Buttons inside the TableLayoutPanel, the Buttons
> are not automatically inserted at the Top-Left position of the cell
> and instead they appear positioned in a random place, then the
> TableLayoutPanel has *gone rogue* and needs to be put down. Delete it
> and drop another on the Form. Rinse and repeat.
>
> *This may happen if you tamper with the layout a bit. Better start over than trying to correct the problem*.

[TableLayoutPanel Control Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview)