# How do you make a TextBox height resize when dockstyle is set to fill?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

When I set a TextBox dock style to Fill inside a TableLayoutPanel cell, only the width resizes while the height remains the same.

How do I make the height fill out the TableLayoutPanel's cell?

Comment: Set its `MultiLine` property to true, coupled with a fixed `MaxLength`, if needed. The TLP `MinimumSize` can also help. Also, see the notes here: [How can I link a component's Size to the Window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829513/7444103).

Comment: In questions related to UI components you should edit your question and add the relevant tags. For example `winforms` vs `wpf`

Comment: BTW: I think this is winforms because of `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: @Jimi OH thanks haha cant believe i didnt think of that, i use multiline textbox all the time

Comment: aw man guys dont mark my question as duplicate, i was searching for the answer on stack overflow too but i just cant find a question related to dockstyle, i think different ways of phrasing a question can help users find an answer easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that you need to set `MultiLine` to `true`.